# mongoose check if id exists but that id is nested inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When i fetch new alerts, i want to check if the ID of the new alert was already recorded. The issue is that that ID is nested inside an array. There's the alertsDetails array, which contains objects and those objects have an _ID filed which is what i want to check. I am not sure how to achieve that. I got the code below but then i have to iterate over the result to check the exists value. Im sure there must be a better way.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const G2AlertsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    status: { type: String, required: true },
    openDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    alertType: { type: Array, required: true },
    severity: { type: Array, required: true },
    locationName: { type: Array, required: true },
    history: { type: Array, required: true },
    alertDetails: { type: Array, required: false },
    assignedTo: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const G2Alerts = mongoose.model('G2Alert', G2AlertsSchema);

module.exports = G2Alerts;
```

This is the code i found on mongodb's website. I just want to see if the ID exists only. Basically when i fetch the new alerts i get an array and i iterate over it, i want to check each item's ID against what's inside the Database. If it's there, skip and go to the next. If it's new, then create a new alert and save it.

```
 const exists = await G2Alerts.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        exists: {
          $in: ['5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343', '$alertDetails._id'],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

**EDIT:** Another thing. I am getting a eslint warning saying i should use array iteration instead of a for loop. The issue is, i need to use await when looking up the Alert ID. If i use, reduce or filter, i can't use await. If i use async inside the reduce or filter function, then it will return promises in or just an empty array.

This below works, based on the answer provided by **Tom Slabbaert**

```
  const newAlertsData = [];

  for (let item of alertData.data.items) {
    const exists = await G2Alerts.find({ 'alertDetails._id': `${item._id}` });
    if (exists.length === 0) {
      newAlertsData.push(item);
    }
  }

  if (newAlertsData.length !== 0) {......
```

But this does not

```
  const filteredAlerts = alertData.data.items.reduce((filtered, item) => {
    const exists = await G2Alerts.find({ 'alertDetails._id': `${item._id}` });
    if (exists.length === 0) {
      filtered.push(item);
    }
    return filtered;
  }, []);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far off, here is an example using the correct syntax:

```
const exists = await G2Alerts.findOne({"alertDetails._id": '5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343'}});
if (!exists) {
    ... do something
}
```

This can also be achieve using `aggregate` with a `$match` stage instead of a `$project` stage or even better [countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) which just returns the count instead of the entire object if you do not require it.

One more thing I'd like to add is that make sure `alertDetails._id` is `string` type as you're using `string` in you're `$in`. otherwise you'll need to cast them to `ObjectId` type in mongoose like so:

```
new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343')
```

And for Mongo:

```
import {ObjectId} from "mongodb"
...


new ObjectId('5f0b4f508bda3805754ab343')
```

---

EDIT

Try something like this?

```
let ids = alertData.data.items.map(item => item._id.toString());
let existing = await G2Alerts.distinct("alertsDetails._id", {"alertsDetails._id": {$in: ids}});

const filteredAlerts = alertData.data.items.reduce((filtered, item) => {
    if (!existing.includes(item._id.toString())) {
        return [item].concat(filtered)
    }
    return filtered;
}, []);
```

This way you only need to call the db once and not multiple times.

Final code based on the provided answer.

```
  const ids = alertData.data.items.map(item => item._id);
  const existing = await G2Alerts.find({ 'alertDetails._id': { $in: ids } }).distinct(
    'alertDetails._id',
    (err, alerts) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      return alerts;
    },
  );

  const filteredAlerts = alertData.data.items.reduce((filtered, item) => {
    if (!existing.includes(item._id.toString()) && item.openDate > dateLimit) {
      return [item].concat(filtered);
    }
    return filtered;
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! i added an edit about a eslint warning i am getting. Was wondering if you knew a way around that? Also my code seems to run faster if i just use a for loop

Comment: one more thing !exists does not work, as it returns an empty array so there is something being returned. I had to do exists.length === 0

Comment: You're right, should have used `findOne` instead of `find` for that. the new code snippet you posted that doesn't work is becaue of the async nature if the `find` combined with the `reduce` function. while it's possible to make that work why not just 1 find and then filter? added on edit.

Comment: What do you mean by 1 find and then filter?  My problem is the alerts come in as an array of objects. Each object has a unique ID. I want to check each one of them for existence in my database before i create a new entry. The code checks every 5 min and if there is a new one i want to add it. But if there is an older alert that was not resolved, it will come in with the array as well and i don't want to add it. I also try to combine these alerts, because sometime it is generated by the same charge point but it gives one alert for each of the power plugs of that charge point, so 4 alerts forone

Comment: I meant fetch all -exisiting- (out of the possible new ones) ids first. and then iterate over the alrams and filter. I added a pueso code snippet to my answer to portray that. this way is just more efficient as you only have 1 db call instead of `alertData.data.items` db calls in order to filter. the way you wrote it is also possible but you need to resolve your promises correctly to do so.

Comment: Doesn't work. IDs returns a list of the IDs, existing returns an empty array, i assume because those IDs already exist but the filteredAlerts still returns an array with all the alerts, including the existing ones.

Comment: if existing is empty then filteredAlers will be all of the alerts as it's using the exisiting array to filter it out. this is probably due to a type mismatch between `ObjectId` and `string` types. because you didn't include a full schema and types of the code I guessed the type using the code in your snippet. just resolve this isssue and it should work (remember js `.includes` does not work on ObjectId so you will have to cast the array to be `string` type).

Comment: I added an image of the results. The IDs in the alerts come in as strings not objectIds i believe

Comment: if `await G2Alerts.find({ 'alertDetails._id': "${item._id}" })` than `await G2Alerts.distinct("alertsDetails._id", {"alertsDetails._id": {$in: ids}});` should work as well as it's practically the same query. make sure the one you posted works

Comment: i added the final solution to your answer. None of the methods above worked but this one does. Thanks for your help :)